# Switching between tabs in android

Tags: android-widget

Hi I Have 3 tabs in one sceen..
first tab:some edittext fields with some  data in disable mode.initially only one button will be there ie "edit",when u click "edit" then fields will change to editable mode.and "save","cancel" buttons will come.

My Requirment:if we change data in edittext fields and if u are  trying to change tab I should display an alert box saying that "do u want to save data?"

can any one tell how can i achive this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement OnTabChangeListner in main activity and in this check whether edit text is in editable mode.u can check it by using a flag. set flag when user press on edit button. if flag is true then show alert.